# How do I back up my Azure SQL Server Database to my local machine?

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure

I have an Azure SQL Server database that I need to get rid of off of Azure, but that I don't want to lose the data within it.

I cannot figure out how to backup/export the data.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can export it to storage then download the export to your local machine.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had exhausted my search, but I finally found this answer on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48617558/2044